# Watchkit and Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, watchkit

I can return snapshot.value for the first time to Apple Watch...

How to return snapshot.value for the second time (e.g. someone else updated the database with new data) firebase1 observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded being triggered?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply {

    [firebase1 observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot){
        reply(snapshot.value);
    }]
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly: your `observeEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:` is already triggered on those updates, right? If so, the question is specifically how to send multiple responses to watchkit for a single extension request.

Comment: This seems promising: http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-actionable-notifications/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, thx for replying. you understand my question correctly. I want to know how to send multiple responses/reply to watchkit for a single watch extension request. Currently after sending a reply back, I can't figure out how to send another reply to the watch... Can you please guide me? I'm not working on notifications though. Just pushing back the reply to the apple watch app.

Comment: I'm quite sure a single method call can only return a single result, unless Apple worked some async-magic in there. I could only find more when searching in the direction of notifications. But I'm definitely not an Apple/Watchkit expert. Hopefully one of those drops by soon, because I'd also love to learn how to implement this type of user interaction.